# How to call a generator type function with a nonetype function within a loop?

Tags: python, class, generator, yield

I have a generator function getElements in a class Reader() that yields all the elements out of an xml file. I also want to have a function getFeatures that only yields the elements with a feature tag.

How I tried it is to have a flag featuresOnly that is set to True when getFeatures is called, and in getFeatures call self.getElements, like this:

```
def getFeatures(self):
    self.getFeaturesOnly = True
    self.getElements()
```

This way in getElements() I only have to do

```
def getElements(self):
    inFile = open(self.path)
    for element in cElementTree.iterparse(inFile):
        if self.getFeaturesOnly == True:
            if element.tag == 'feature':
                yield element
        else:
            yield element
     inFile.close()
```

However, when I do this and run it

```
 features = parseFeatureXML.Reader(filePath)
 for element in features.getFeatures():#
       print element
```

I get: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
This is because getFeatures doesn't contain a yield. Now, the way that I know how to solve this is to copy the code of getElements into getFeatures and only use the

```
if elementFunctions.getElmentTag(element) == 'feature':
```

in the getFeatures() function, but  I rather not duplicate any code. So how would I be able to keep on generator function, and have a different function where I only specefy which tag I would like to get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first: **You have that error because you don't return the generator**

Meaning that you have to change:

```
def getFeatures(self):
    self.getFeaturesOnly = True
    self.getElements()
```

with:

```
def getFeatures(self):
    self.getFeaturesOnly = True
    return self.getElements()    # returning the generator
```

Cleared this, TBH I wouldn't design my `Reader()` class like this.

I'd let the `getElement` yield all the elements:

```
def getElements(self):
    inFile = open(self.path)
    for element in cElementTree.iterparse(inFile):
        yield element
    inFile.close()
```

And then `getFeatures()` do the filtering:

```
def getFeatures(self):
    for element in self.getElements():
        if element.tag == 'feature':
            yield element
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get the `TypeError` is not that `getFeatures` doesn't contain a yield, it's because `getFeatures` *doesn't return anything*. If you want `getFeatures` to return the iterator returned by `getElements`, you have to use `return`:

```
def getFeatures(self):
    self.getFeaturesOnly = True
    return self.getElements()
```

While you're at it, you really shouldn't do `if expr == True`; just do `if expr`, which works even if `expr` is true (the concept) but not `True` (the object.) That said, instead of hoisting the features-only support into `getElements`, a more common approach is to do it in `getFeatures` itself, like so:

```
def getFeatures(self):
    for element in self.getElements():
        if element.tag == 'feature':
            yield element

def getElements(self):
    inFile = open(self.path)
    for element in cElementTree.iterparse(inFile):
        yield element
    inFile.close()
```